# Deactivate vmtoolsd on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, performance, vmware, services

I have a server on a virtual machine which was not setup by myself. As we experience some hiccups from time to time I am trying to cleanup everything that is not needed. `top` shows that the `vmtoolsd` service is using the most CPU time on the machine:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
984 root      20   0  163820   6616   5216 S   0,0   0,0 273:46.24 vmtoolsd
573 root      19  -1  223316 130796 128016 S   0,0   0,4 251:22.61 systemd-journal
608 root      20   0   22036   3412   2804 S   0,0   0,0 228:10.25 systemd-udevd
```

The [VMWare documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tools/11.2.5/com.vmware.vsphere.vmwaretools.doc/GUID-FB7FA658-7622-4680-BD9F-7A6670C12794.html) states that the process is used for the following:

- Enables copy and paste of text between guest operating system and [...] host
- grabs and releases the pointer if the SVGA driver is not installed
- fits the screen display resolution of the guest to the screen resolution of the [...] host
- allows you to drag files between the host operating system and [...] guest

The server does not have any graphical user interface running. It is only accessed via SSH, Samba and FTP, and it serves a web page. Is it safe to disable the service without interfering with anything else on the machine?